# Datatables not working when placed in one single webpart?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, visual-studio, visual-web-part, sharepoint-server, datatable

We have added two datatables in one single webpart. And when one of the datatable is empty the search function does not work for the other one which has data. Why does that happen? Or how can we implement search by that side?

Comment: what search? webpart search or main search bar?

Comment: Data Tables search.

Comment: Issue solved we have to pass one null record. Instead displaying some text when empty. And if we pass null value as one record, when there are no records functionality of all the datatables in the same web part work fine

Comment: glad to see you solved the issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved we have to pass one null record. Instead displaying some text when empty. And if we pass null value as one record, when there are no records functionality of all the datatables in the same web part work fine